# Unable to send email using smtp in C# in console application

Tags: c#, .net, smtp

I am learning sending basic email using smtp in C#.
Here is my code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Sending email..");
                const string fromEmail = "abc@gmail.com";
                const string pswd = "password";
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

                message.From = new MailAddress(fromEmail);
                message.To.Add(new MailAddress("abc@gmail.com"));
                message.Subject = "Email Testing";
                message.Body = "This is email testing. It is working as expected. Thanks";
                message.IsBodyHtml = false;
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromEmail, pswd);
                smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtp.Send(message);

                Console.WriteLine("Email sent successfully");
```

When I am running it it is simply throwing below exception:

```
Failure sending mail.
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   at EmailDemo.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

It is throwing error at smtp.Send() method but I am not able to follow the exception properly. Am I missing any configuration? I am sure fromemail and pswd is correct. Only thing is from and to email address is same.
Need help on this.
PS: I am adding the password generated from App Passwords in google accounts.

Comment: From the documentation of SmtpClient "We don't recommend that you use the SmtpClient class for new development because SmtpClient doesn't support many modern protocols. Use MailKit or other libraries instead."

Comment: I do not see anything modern here. Can you point out the area where the error possibly can be?

Comment: @joma,I saw an earlier post where the same code was failing to send the mail silently and its because of the reasons stated by Ralf.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled IMAP for your gmail account?
If not, follow [this guide](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en#zippy=%2Cstep-check-that-imap-is-turned-on).

Comment: I did this but still it is not working